# Class not inheriting property initialization status

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have this situation where when I inherit a class the properties in the base class aren't recognized as being initialized in the extended class. I'm not sure if this is an issue with typescript or tslint and I couldn't find anything on google (maybe not searching the right things).

> (property) BaseClass.myProperty: IMyProperty | undefined Object is
>   possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

**example.ts**

```
interface IMyProperty{
  myName: string;
}

class BaseClass {
  readonly myProperty: IMyProperty | undefined;
  constructor(options: IMyProperty){
    this.myProperty = options
  }
}

class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass{
  constructor(options: IMyProperty){
    super(options)
  }

  printMyName(){
    console.log(this.myProperty.myName); // <-- Complains about this
  }
}

const extendedClass = new ExtendedClass({myName: 'John Smith'});
extendedClass.printMyName();
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you're declaring that `myProperty` can be undefined, TypeScript must complain about accessing a possibly undefined value. This is because TS has no way of knowing if you don't reassigns the value somewhere else in the code.

```
const extendedClass = new ExtendedClass({myName: 'John Smith'});
extendedClass.myProperty = undefined
extendedClass.printMyName(); // Would throw a runtime error.
```

In order to fix this issue, you have to add a guard checking if the value is defined properly at the execution time.

```
class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass {
  printMyName() {
    // if (this.myProperty) { ... } would also work.
    if (typeof this.myProperty !== 'undefined') {
      console.log(this.myProperty.myName); // Now it works. TS know it can't be undefined at this point.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I set as readonly. I really don't want to add a guard because the property will be used a lot. Also it doesn't complain if it is withing the BaseClass constructor.

Comment: `readonly` can't guarantee that a runtime code won't change anything so TS is still right. Try `extendedClass['my' + 'Property'] = undefined` and see it will work. If you're really sure you don't want to secure the code, you can use `!` to ensure TS about the property existence: `this.myProperty!.myName`.

Answer (score -1):

In your `console.log()` statement you're trying to log myName, but as the compiler error says, `this.myProperty` is possibly undefined. Therefore this statement is not allowed because you cannot access a property (myName) of an object (this.myProperty) that is undefined.

Why can `myProperty` be undefined at all? Can you just remove the `| undefined` in BaseClass? This would solve your problem.

Comment: It is being initialized outside from outside the class. I want BaseClass.myProperty to be undefinable but all instances of ExtendedClass should expect to have myProperty initalized.

Comment: Then as Mateusz said you should either use the non-null assertion operator `!`, or assert that `myProperty` is not undefined in the `ExtendedClass` constructor or in `printMyName()`

Comment: Unfortunately even if I assert it in the extended class I still have to explicitly assign it in the extended class. Even though the base class already does that.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this kinds of solves this issue but still doesn't seem very elegant

```
interface IMyProperty {
    myName: string;
}

class BaseClass {
    readonly myProperty: IMyProperty | undefined;
    constructor(options: IMyProperty) {
        this.myProperty = options
    }
}

class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass {
    readonly myProperty: IMyProperty;

    constructor(options: IMyProperty) {
        super(options);
        this.myProperty = options;
    }

    printMyName() {
        console.log(this.myProperty.myName);
    }
}

const extendedClass = new ExtendedClass({ myName: 'John Smith' });
extendedClass.printMyName();
```